# Multi-conditional join through a link table

Tags: mysql

Bear with me, this needs a lot of up front info to explain what I am trying to do. I have tried to genericize it as much as possible to make things clearer. In a single query I am hoping to pull out a list of pages which match against tags linked in another table, and these tags are in groups. I am hoping to use the textual representation of the item instead of it's id, but if nothing else I could do 2 up front queries to get the tag_id and taggroup_id - just hoping not to have to do that.

DB Schema:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| taggroups                         |
+------------------+----------------+
| taggroup_id      | group_name     |
+------------------+----------------+
| 1                | fruits         |
+------------------+----------------+

+-----------------------------------------------+
| tags                                          |
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+
| tag_id      | taggroup_id     | tag_name      |
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+
| 1           | 1               | apple         |
| 2           | 1               | orange        |
| 3           | 1               | grape         |
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+

+--------------------------------------+
| pages                                |
+------------------+-------------------+
| page_id          | title             |
+------------------+-------------------+
| 99               | Doctor a day      |
+------------------+-------------------+

+--------------------------------------------------+
| tags_to_pages                                    |
+------------+----------+---------------+----------+
| join_id    | tag_id   | taggroup_id   | page_id  |
+------------+----------+---------------+----------+
| 1          | 1        | 1             | 99       |
| 2          | 2        | 1             | 99       |
+------------+----------+---------------+----------+
```

Test Query:
Got this far and can't seem to get it to work.

```
SELECT
    pages.*, tags.tag_name, taggroups.group_name
FROM
    tags_to_pages
    INNER JOIN taggroups as grp ON (
            grp.group_name = 'fruits'
        AND
            tags_to_pages.taggroup_id = grp.taggroup_id
    )
    INNER JOIN tags as val ON (val.tag_name = 'apple' AND tags_to_pages.tag_id = val.tag_id)
    LEFT JOIN pages ON (tags_to_pages.page_id = pages.page_id)
```

Additionally, what tables should have indexes and what should the indexes be for be optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
SELECT
    pages.*, tags.tag_name, taggroups.group_name
FROM
    tags_to_pages
    JOIN taggroups AS grp ON grp.taggroup_id = tags_to_pages.taggroup_id
    JOIN tags AS val ON val.taggroup_id = grp.taggroup_id
    JOIN pages ON tags_to_pages.page_id = pages.page_id
WHERE
    grp.group_name='fruits'
    AND val.tag_name = 'apple'
```

This isn't *that* different to what you have, but I'm putting the join criteria in the `JOIN` clauses and the selection criteria in the `WHERE` clauses, which seems tidier to me.

While re-typing this query I spotted that you were using a tag_id somewhere I thought should have been a taggroup_id, so I changed it, but I regret I can't see it again now.

I'd also worry about the selection criteria - what if an apple doesn't happed to be a fruit? Obviously it is in this case, and indeed in reality :-), but I think you should only be specifying the fruit name in your query, not fruit and group names, and leave the database to sort it out for itself.

Also, why use an `INNER JOIN` for tags, tags_to_pages and taggroups and an OUTER JOIN for pages? Surely if there are no pages, you're better of getting no rows returned rather than one row, half full on NULLS?

I'd index the id columns only.

Just my 2p worth, really.

**EDIT**

I have set up a demo of this on [www.sqlfiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b070/16). Your [original query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b070/16/1) worked fine once I changed the aliases in the `SELECT` list. My [attempt above](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b070/18/2) didn't work terribly well :-(. I had the same problems with the aliases and once I fixed them the query returned the same row twice.

I re-wrote it again from scratch as

```
SELECT pages.*, tags.tag_name, taggroups.group_name
FROM pages
JOIN tags_to_pages AS ttp ON ttp.page_id = pages.page_id
JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = ttp.tag_id
JOIN taggroups ON taggroups.taggroup_id = ttp.taggroup_id
WHERE taggroups.group_name = 'fruits' AND tags.tag_name='apple';
```

and it works fine [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b070/18/0).

Setting up this demo, it struck me to wonder why you were saving the `taggroup_id` in the `tags_to_pages` table. I'm "self-taught" in SQL and databases (translate that to: "I make it up as I go along, rely on doing things that 'work' and trust to intuition to find out what's 'right'") but doesn't this break the idea of normalisation? Shouldn't the connection between `tags` and `taggroups` be defined only via the `taggroup_id` column in the `tags` table? Perhaps someone who *really* understands databases will come along and put me right.

Finally, I've no idea why PHPMyAdmin just hung up when you tried your query. Good luck!

Comment: As you may guess from the currency unit above, I'm in the UK and it's getting rather late, so I'm off to bed now - I'll respond to any comments in the morning - i.e. 10 hours time. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks nurd, did you just change the structure of the query or also the logic behind it. E.g. is it doing the the same thing just in a different manner? Because I couldn't get my query to work in the first place.

Comment: Blast - too slow to get to bed! I changed to JOIN on taggroupid rather than tag_id somewhere :-| WHat problem were you getting when the query "wouldn't work"? Was it returning nothing, or was it returning "the wrong stuff"?

Comment: In PHPMyAdmin it just sits there processing, no error, no results. Normal queries return right away. Running local too, so it's not a memory or large db problem.

Comment: Thanks so much, looks like this is working great. You are correct, the extra group_id is not needed - removing that. Also thank you for the discovery of SQLFIDDLE, this is a great utility.